# Delphi XE3 Firemonkey OS X - TComboBox hangs application

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I have run into a problem which is very easy to recreate:

1. Create a new FireMonkey HD application, put a TComboBox on the form and add a few items to it.
2. Run the application in OS X (v. 10.8.2 in my case, but it has also been tested on 10.6.8).
3. Click the combobox, but don't finish by clicking an item. Instead, "change your mind" and click somewhere else on the form.
4. Wait for a few seconds and watch the "spinning beachball of death". The application hangs, nothing happens in the debugger.

Anyone who knows anything about this bug? A workaround would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If it's on a form with Transparent = True then it's a known issue, otherwise it's new to me (which may not mean much).

Comment: No, in this case Transparent = False. I will check if tranparency may be involved in my original problem, though, so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This bug was introduced in XE3 Update 2. 
So you can go back to Update 1... or just roll back the one source package that introduced this: FMX.Platform.mac.pas

See also: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=84315&tstart=0